# How do you test a response that's not returned by lower method?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, python-responses

I am trying to write a test for class that makes a post request to an external API. I'm using the [responses](https://pypi.org/project/responses/) library to mock the external service after recording a real response (so this test is designed to run with either a real connection to the external service or without).

I'm having trouble making sure the mocked response is correct. The issue is that the method I'm testing doesn't return the actual `response` object--just a specific parameter of the json response. I'm wondering how to access the response object that's in a lower level of the call stack(? <<this might be the wrong terminology).

This is an excerpt of the test:

```
ls = Client(url=LABEL_STUDIO_URL, api_key=API_KEY)
ls.check_connection()
ls.delete_all_projects()
# Create a sample project to classify types of texts
project = ls.start_project(
    title="Text Type Classifications",
    label_config="""
    <View>
    <Text name="text" value="$text"/>
    <View style="box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #999;
                   padding: 20px; margin-top: 2em;
                   border-radius: 5px;">
        <Header value="Choose text type"/>
        <Choices name="type" toName="text"
                choice="single" showInLine="true">
        <Choice value="Title"/>
          <Choice value="Narrative"/>
        </Choices>
    </View>
    </View>
    """,
)
label_studio_data = label_studio.stage_for_label_studio(elements)
imported_ids = project.import_tasks(label_studio_data)
```

The issue is that `project.import_tasks` returns `response.json()['task_ids']`, so I'm wondering how, from my test where I init a `project`, I can test more than just the `task-ids` from the response.

```
def import_tasks(self, tasks, preannotated_from_fields: List = None):
    """Import JSON-formatted labeling tasks. Tasks can be unlabeled or contain predictions.
        Parameters
        ----------
        tasks: list of dicts | dict | path to file
            Tasks in <a href="https://labelstud.io/guide/tasks.html#Basic-Label-Studio-JSON-format">
            Label Studio JSON format</a>

        preannotated_from_fields: list of strings
            Turns flat task JSON formatted like: `{"column1": value, "column2": value}` into Label Studio prediction
            data format: `{"data": {"column1"..}, "predictions": [{..."column2"}]`
            Useful when all your data is stored in tabular format with one column dedicated to model predictions.

        Returns
        -------
        list of int
            Imported task IDs

        """
        params = {'return_task_ids': '1'}
        if preannotated_from_fields:
            params['preannotated_from_fields'] = ','.join(preannotated_from_fields)
        if isinstance(tasks, (list, dict)):
            response = self.make_request(
                method='POST',
                url=f'/api/projects/{self.id}/import',
                json=tasks,
                params=params,
            )
        elif isinstance(tasks, (str, Path)):
            # try import from file
            if not os.path.isfile(tasks):
                raise LabelStudioException(f'Not found import tasks file {tasks}')
            with open(tasks, mode='rb') as f:
                response = self.make_request(
                    method='POST',
                    url=f'/api/projects/{self.id}/import',
                    files={'file': f},
                    params=params,
                )
        else:
            raise TypeError(
                f'Not supported type provided as "tasks" argument: {type(tasks)}'
            )
        return response.json()['task_ids']
```